# Cannot open dart dev tools in flutter web --profile

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I've been looking all over the internet but couldn't find anything relevant. Regarding flutter web profile (dev tools)

1. Why can't I open dart dev tools in flutter web profile mode?
2. if can't open dev tools in web (profile mode) how to test performance and memory logs?[image][image]

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Christian as of now dev tools is not supported in flutter profile mode i've opened an issue regarding this [check it out](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3969)

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking back. So how are you profiling your web app then? Do you use the chrome devtools?

Comment: yes. But we cannot do indepth inspection like we do in dart dev tools